# Can you undo 'blackening' from Chromium after exposure to bleach?

Tags: metallurgy

I accidentally used toilet cleaner (instead of bathroom cleaner) containing bleach on a Chromed tap/faucet which has resulted in an black clouding over the surface of the chrome. It doesn't seem to polish out or clean off even with metal polish.

Is there any way to reverse this process or will I have to replace or chrome plate the tap?

Comment: From what I've been able to search for, there doesn't seem to be a way to reverse the chemical corrosion that occurred to the chrome metal. Perhaps an electrochemical approach can be taken to electroplate new chromium ions onto the surface.